# PC turns off/log outs when disconnected from TV

Tags: hdmi, remote

For some reason when I disconnect the HDMI cable from the pc it turns off/log out. When I reconnect the HDMI cable back it just outputs a black screen and I have to restart the PC. When I try to remote control the pc it shows as offline when its in that state.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using?  What GPU or iGPU is being used?  What kind of display is this?  Is this a laptop?  Are there any other displays?  Can you determine if the PC **turns off** or **logs out**?

Comment: Gtx 970 as a display. Ubuntu 21.04. Its a desktop theres no other displays. I cant tell whats happening since the pc lights stay on but all programs running on the pc turn off and when i reconnect it to a display it just outputs a black screen and doesnt respond to any inputs

Comment: The GTX 970 is a graphics card.  It's not a display.  I am asking about your display because you called it a TV.  What lights stay on? What do you mean the programs turn off? Explain what you are talking about when you try to "remote control" the PC.  Please be explicit and completely clear in your details. You should be exact.  Any ambiguity means we can't know what you're describing.  Ex. What is "remote control"?  Are you trying to connect ssh? What is the exact error you receive?  Remember we aren't there and we can't access your device so we only can go off what you tell us.